# Как мутировать объект в store (redux), на который есть ссылки?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

По мере углубления в **react-redux** возникли следующие вопросы:
в-1: Как можно изменить значение полей объекта (экземпляра класса), хранящегося в store, **сохранив** при этом корректность **ссылок на него из других объектов** (также хранящихся в store). 
в-2: Существуют ли паттерны, пакеты npm на этот случай?
*При этом имеются такие соображения:

с-01: Как я понимаю, для того, чтобы сохранить иммутабельность, необходимо деструктурировать объект (глубоко) и собрать заново, но ведь при этом потеряется **ссылка на него из других объектов**?!

с-02: Чем грозит *прямое* изменение значения поля объекта? Только тем, что store не заметит изменения? Очевидно, так и происходит. Однако это обходится изменением соответствующего флага в store (который также передается в mapStateToProps с массивом содержащим соответствующий объект; mapStateToProps срабатывает на изменение флага и заодно обновляет props'ы) и все прекрасно срабатывает! Или, все же, - это непозволительный костыль?

с-03: Или можно переструктурировать мутируемый объект (который также включает ссылки на другие объекты), создав новый, а затем просто напрямую присвоить его значению, хранящему ссылку на предыдущий (previous) объект в store? Но это, кажется, еще большее нарушение принципа иммутабельности?* 
Спасибо отреагировавшим и, особенно, ответившим!

P.S. Оказалось, задача (см. выше) легко решается на MobX!

Comment: Создайте, пожалуйста, [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Вопрос теоретический или вы проект какой-то пишете? Продемонстрируйте, пожалуйста, все то, что вы говорите в коде. Опишите фактическое поведение и то, что в нем смущает, чего хотелось бы. По моему мнению, таким длинным повествованием вы рискуете запутать сами себя и все сообщество заодно. В первую очередь ,покажите, что за "ссылки из других объектов", которые дважды жирным выделены в тексте и какие конкретно проблемы с ними возникают?

Comment: Ответ простой - не надейтесь на ссылки. Используйте id, организуйте хранение объектов по другому. В идеале, свойство в сторе ничего не должно знать о соседних свойствах. Вся логика - в редьюсерах\эффектах.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Постараюсь переформулировать вопрос. Перерыл довольно много ресурсов, но прямого ответа не нашел. Вопрос комплексный, т.е. накладывающий ряд взаимных ограничений на отдельные "правильные" решения. Да, для store лучше не использовать ссылки. Да, логику рекомендовано размещать в редьюсерах\эффектах. В основе моей модели данных - семантическая сеть, в узлах - экз-ы классов со своей логикой. Связывать, затем искать узлы по id, а не по ссылке - замедлить и усложнить код. Вынести логику наружу - нарушить основной принцип ОПП, а хотелось бы использовать ее преимуществами